# How do i debug XAML and is there any bugs in this current code

Tags: xaml, debugging

Sorry I know this is probably a stupid question but I am learning to program apps using Xamarin, and I am not sure how to debug XAML. Are there any useful tips or tools I can use in debugging XAML in Visual Studio? Also is there anything wrong within this code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorld2.EntryPage">

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button Text="Next" TextColor="Blue" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Font Size: {0}'}" />
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="16" Maximum="100" />
        <Label x:Name="quoteLabel" FontSize="{Binding Value}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What is the BindingContext for in your stacklayout? I think you can take that out

Comment: I put BindingContext on the StackLayout so I don't have to write out the entire reference for both of of the labels in it. I'll try removing it and referencing them for each object.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, in the slider, Maximum must be declared before the Minimum. Why? Because that is how it is.